# How can I properly block a thread until timeout starts?

Tags: java, threadpool

I would like to run several tasks in parallel until a certain amount of time has passed. Let us suppose those threads are CPU-heavy and/or may block indefinitely. After the timeout, the threads should be interrupted immediately, and the main thread should continue execution regardless of unfinished or still running tasks.

I've seen a lot of questions asking this, and the answers were always similar, often along the lines of "create thread pool for tasks, start it, join it on timeout"

The problem is between the "start" and "join" parts. As soon as the pool is allowed to run, it may grab CPU and the timeout will not even start until I get it back.

I have tried Executor.invokeAll, and found that it did not fully meet the requirements. Example:

```
    long dt = System.nanoTime ();
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool (4);
    List <Callable <String>> list = new ArrayList <> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add (new Callable <String> () {
            @Override
            public String call () throws Exception {
                while (true) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
    System.out.println ("Start at " + (System.nanoTime () - dt) / 1000000 + "ms");
    try {
        pool.invokeAll (list, 3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    System.out.println ("End at " + (System.nanoTime () - dt) / 1000000 + "ms");
```

> Start at 1ms
>   End at 3028ms

This (27 ms delay)  may not seem too bad, but an infinite loop is rather easy to break out of - the actual program experiences ten times more easily. My expectation is that a timeout request is met with very high accuracy even under heavy load (I'm thinking along the lines of a hardware interrupt, which should *always* work).

This is a major pain in my particular program, as it needs to heed certain timeouts rather accurately (for instance, around 100 ms, if possible better). However, starting the pool often takes as long as 400 ms until I get control back, pushing past the deadline.

I'm a bit confused why this problem is almost never mentioned. Most of the answers I have seen definitely suffer from this. I suppose it may be acceptable usually, but in my case it's not.

Is there a clean and tested way to go ahead with this issue?

**Edited to add:**

My program is involved with GC, even though not on a large scale. For testing purposes, I rewrote the above example and found that the results given are very inconsistent, but on average noticeably worse than before.

```
    long dt = System.nanoTime ();
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool (40);
    List <Callable <String>> list = new ArrayList <> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add (new Callable <String> () {
            @Override
            public String call () throws Exception {
                String s = "";
                while (true) {
                    s += Long.toString (System.nanoTime ());
                    if (s.length () > 1000000) {
                        s = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    System.out.println ("Start at " + (System.nanoTime () - dt) / 1000000 + "ms");
    try {
        pool.invokeAll (list, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    System.out.println ("End at " + (System.nanoTime () - dt) / 1000000 + "ms");
```

> Start at 1ms
>   End at 1189ms

Comment: I've just found this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-rtj1/ and will start reading it now. It should touch upon your problem, too.

Comment: @laune Thanks for the link. Upon a glance, it appears to confirm my fear that my expectations are (far) too high :(

Comment: These expectations may be too high even when you use another language. You are getting into a dimension where a RT operating system is indicated, although it's possible that a different design *might* make it feasible in something like C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

`invokeAll` should work just fine.  However, it is vital that you write your tasks to properly respond to interrupts.  When catching InterruptedException, they should exit immediately.  If your code is catching IOException, each such catch-block should be preceded with something like:

```
} catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
    logger.log(Level.FINE, "Interrupted; exiting", e);
    return;
}
```

If you are using [Channels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html), you will want to handle [ClosedByInterruptException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ClosedByInterruptException.html) the same way.

If you perform time-consuming operations that don't catch the above exceptions, you need to check [Thread.interrupted()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted--) periodically.  Obviously, checking more often is better, though there will be a point of diminishing returns.  (Meaning, checking it after every single statement in your task probably isn't useful.)

```
if (Thread.interrupted()) {
    logger.fine("Interrupted; exiting");
    return;
}
```

In your example code, your Callable is not checking the interrupt status at all, so my guess is that it *never* exits.  An interrupt does not actually stop a thread; it just signals the thread that it should terminate itself on its own terms.

Comment: The actual program does check for interrupts regularly, however, in quite different time intervals. I will attempt to increase the frequency and check the results.

Comment: I found that this made no difference in my use case, I'll add my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Using the VM option `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`, I found that the GC runs more rarely, but with a far larger time delay than expected. That delay just so happens to coincide with the spikes I experienced.

A mundane and sad explanation for the observed behavior.

Comment: There are a lot of advanced tuning options that may be able to help you.  They're all listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABFAFAE).  I don't know enough about GC to says which ones are best, but the parallel GC options and `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis` seem promising.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those. The MaxPauseMillis sadly did not reduce delay in my tests. Maybe I can further reduce instance creation count to at least make the problem less prominent.